# Why `synchronized (lock)` was entered twice by different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, synchronized-block

In this simple example I have two `synchronized (theLock)` that are accessed by different threads

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("start");

        final Object theLock = new Object();

        synchronized (theLock) {
            System.out.println("main thread id : " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

            new Thread(() -> {
                System.out.println("new thread id : " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ". Inside thread");

                // before entering this section new thread should be blocked as `theLock` is already acquired
                synchronized (theLock) {
                    System.out.println("inside synchronized");
                    theLock.notify();
                }
            }).start();

            theLock.wait();
        }

        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

Why the newly created thread can access to `synchronized (theLock)` section inside? As far as I understand, `theLock` is already acquired by the main thread and the new one should block forever. Instead I see that it enters to `synchronized` as well.

Here is an output

```
start
main thread id : 1 
new thread id : 13. Inside thread
inside synchronized
end
```

Comment: The original thread calls `theLock.wait()` which means it _releases the lock_ and waits to be notified. Then the second thread obtains the lock, calls `notify`, and releases the lock. Then the first thread wakes up, obtains the lock, and continues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `wait()` releases the lock. [Per `wait()` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) (bolding mine):

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the
>   `notify()` method or the `notifyAll()` method for this object. In
>   other words, this method behaves exactly as if it simply performs the
>   call `wait(0)`.
>
> The current thread must own this object's monitor. **The thread
>   releases ownership of this monitor** and waits until another thread
>   notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either
>   through a call to the `notify` method or the `notifyAll` method. The
>   thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and
>   resumes execution.